# Why am I getting the 'Welcome to nginx!' page when I launch my Django app with Docker and Nginx?

Tags: django, docker, nginx, gunicorn

My tech stack: Django, Gunicorn, Postgres, Nginx, Docker (and Docker Hub).

I'm currently trying to deploy my web app, and when I launch my website with Docker, I get "Welcome to nginx!" page as a starting page.

Here's dirs of my project:
[dirs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNWtg.png)

Here's the Dockerfile code:

```
FROM python:3.10

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

WORKDIR /code

COPY ./requirements.txt .

RUN pip install --upgrade pip && pip install --upgrade setuptools wheel
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .


EXPOSE 8000
```

Here's docker-compose file code i use to build images (i know this code sucks, so i'll gladly accept critique):

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - type: volume
        source: pg_data
        target: /var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    expose:
      - 5432


  django:
    image: django-docker:0.0.1
    build: .
    command: sh -c "gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 outtask.wsgi"
#    sh -c "gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 outtask.wsgi"
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: .
        target: /outtask
      - type: volume
        source: static_data
        target: /outtask/static
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    expose:
      - 8000
    environment:
    - DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=outtask.settings
    depends_on:
      - db

  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.19.8-alpine
    depends_on:
      - django
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - type: volume
        source: static_data
        target: /outtask/static
      - type: bind
        source: ./nginx-conf.d
        target: /etc/nginx/conf.d

volumes:
  pg_data:
  static_data:
```

Here's how I launch it:
[what I get when launch "docker ps"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9zjRC.png)

nginx.conf code:

```
upstream app {
    server django:8000;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name outtask.ru;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://app;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
     }

    location /static/ {
        alias /outtask/static/;
    }


}
```

My assumptions:
Maybe Nginx isn't ready for deployment and I should add more settings.
Or I may have mixed up directories and Nginx can't see the file "nginx.conf".

Comment: If you're getting the welcome screen it means you haven't properly changed the configuration file for nginx, or you haven't reloaded or restarted the service, but probably the former.